# MVC Kendo UI editable grid with no modal on pop up

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to disable the overlay effect when a user clicks on 'edit'

In popup mode, is there a setting to do that?

It looks like the default setting on pop up mode is to use the overlay, and disable the rest of the page.

**My code**

```
@using mysite.Models

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<UserViewModel>().Name("users_grid").Columns(c =>{
            c.Bound(u => u.UserID);
            c.Bound(u => u.FirstName);
            c.Bound(u => u.LastName);
            c.Bound(u => u.Email);
            c.Bound(u => u.Address);
            c.Bound(u => u.Phone);
            c.Bound(u => u.UserName);
            c.Bound(u => u.UserTypeDisplay).ClientTemplate("#: UserType.Display #").Title("User Type");
            c.Bound(u => u.Company);
            c.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
        })
        .DataSource(d=> d
            .Ajax()
                .Read("ManageUsersajax", "Account")
                .Update(u => u.Action("UpdateUserData", "Account"))
                .Destroy(x => x.Action("Delete", "Products"))
                .Create(c => c.Action("Create", "Products"))
                .PageSize(5)
                        .Model(m =>
                        {
                            m.Id(u => u.UserID);
                            m.Field( u=> u.UserTypeDisplay).DefaultValue(
                                      ViewData["defaultUserType"]);

                        })
        )
        .Pageable()
        .Groupable()
        .Sortable()
         .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
         )

        .ToolBar(t => t.Create())
    )

    <style>



    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you really want is to use the `editable: "inline"` option for the kendo grid. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline

However, if you do actually want the popup with no overlay you can kill the overlay when the edit event is fired by the kendo grid.

http://jsbin.com/beserexi/2/edit?html,js,output

```
edit: function() {
  $('.k-overlay').remove();
}
```

In MVC it should looks something like

```
.Events(events => events.Edit(
        @<text>
            function() {
              $('.k-overlay').remove();
            }
            </text>
         ))
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/grideventbuilder

Comment: and where should i place this script?